# js как заблокировать кнопку submit?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте ребята, прошу помощи. Хочу заблокировать кнопку(submit) по нажатию на неё, чтобы пользователь не отправлял данные формы несколько раз. Когда делаю это перед отправкой формы вот так:

```
obj.disabled=true;
obj.submit();
```

то после disable отправка формы отменяется, а когда наоборот сначала отправляешь данные submit(), а потом блокируешь кнопку, то после отправки формы, кнопка уже не блокируется. Что делать?

Comment: Так вы `disabled = true` делайте для кнопки, а не для формы

Comment: для кнопки делаю, obj это объект кнопки.

Comment: В методе отправки завести флаг, выставлять его при отправке и не делать повторную отправку, если флаг установлен.

Comment: Можно весь код в сборе, с отправкой формы?

Answer (score 1):

Пробуй так:

```
<input type="submit" disabled>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но с самого начала она мне нужна активной, а когда будет нажата, то с помощью js должна стать неактивной.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас jQuery фрейморк. То можно так

```
$('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true); // Блокируем
$('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', false); // Отменяем блокировку
```

Если примерно так реализуете, то при отправки формы, кнопка будет блокироваться

```
$('form').on('submit', function(){
    $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true); // Блокируем
    return true;
});
```

Comment: функция срабатывает, кнопка блокируется, но все равно 'disabled' отменяет отправку формы, страница просто обновляется и ничего не происходит

Comment: @ИгорьСаламов Так вам нужно это повесить на обработчик формы, при отправки что бы срабатывал, сейчас обновлю код

Answer (score 0):

Оот так понятней))
Побуй так :

```
$("#submit").onclick(function () {
    $(".submit").setAttribute(disabled);
  }
);
```

"Это JS

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы публикавать новый ответ, внесите правку в уже существующий ответ.

Comment: Да, и что это за переменная такая - disabled?

Comment: она у меня почему то вообще не запускается, добавляю код $("#submit").onclick(function () {alert('проверка');} ); никакого сообщения не выдает

Comment: disabled / enabled это атрибуты поля, с помощъю которых можно сделать поле активным или же наоборо неактивным для нажатия.

Comment: он наверно имел ввиду, что disable без кавычек.

Comment: Обратите внимание что на вопросе нет метки jquery. Как правило, это означает что ответ ожидается на "чистом" JS